Issue while calling python script from PHP
Pythons script to compress pdf:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from spire.pdf.common import *
from spire.pdf import *
compressor = PdfCompressor("in.pdf")
compression_options = compressor.OptimizationOptions
compression_options.SetIsCompressContents(True)
compression_options.SetIsCompressFonts(True)
compression_options.SetIsCompressImage(True)
compression_options.SetImageQuality(ImageQuality.Medium)
compression_options.SetResizeImages(True)
compressor.CompressToFile("out.pdf")

PHP file to execute code on web server:
$pythonScriptPath = 'convert.py';
// Command to execute the Python script
$command = escapeshellcmd("python3 $pythonScriptPath");
// Execute the command and capture the output
$output = shell_exec($command);
// Output the result
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

I have uploaded this python file on cpanel as convert.py and access it in convert.php.
It is working fine on terminal but in convert.php it is not compressing the pdf file. I have give execute permission to file. Any help will be appreciated.

Please also share output or error.

i am getting white screen. python is working well i checked that only last line is not working. compressor.CompressToFile("out.pdf"). This code is working well in Cpanel Terminal only issue in php script shell_exec()
